# I am trying to draw a circle in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.AliceBlue, New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), New Size(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)))


End Sub
```

I am trying to draw a circle in VB.Net, .Net version 4.
Nothing shows up in the paintbox.

Comment: Are you sure that the paint event is actually firing?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use:

```
e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.AliceBlue,e.ClipRectangle);
```

It worked for me.
You can also try to use:

```
e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(
    Pens.AliceBlue,
    0, 0,
    pictureBox1.Width-1, pictureBox1.Height-1);
```

Or

```
Rectangle rect = e.ClipRectangle;
rect.Inflate(-1, -1);
e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.AliceBlue, rect);
```

Comment: @user366866: did my answer helped you to solve your trouble? :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me, except that `Color.AliceBlue` is almost identical to `KnownColor.Control`.

```
                            rr gg bb
Color.AliceBlue.ToArgb    = F0 F8 FF
KnownColor.Control.ToArgb = F0 F0 F0
Difference                = 00 08 0F
```

Try `Pens.Navy`:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Navy, New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), PictureBox1.Size)) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3fd63x2(v=vs.80).aspx#Y1128

```
' Create pen.
Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)

' Create rectangle for ellipse.
Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200)

' Draw ellipse to screen.
e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackPen, rect)
```

Comment: So, how is this different from the original code? What's the difference that makes it work (as compared to the original code)?

Comment: its the sample MSDN code, if code doesn't work its always good to look at the MSDN sample.  There are slight differences with OPs code.  The OP only provides the code from a single function, if these answers still don't work it suggests it is a different problem which I am sure we will get to the bottom of.